# Redirect incoming traffic based on referrer or random number

Tags: php, url

This working script directs incoming traffic to different locations depending on the value present in the session for referring URI. If there is a present value, it sends the user back to their original location. If not, then a random number is generated, checked against and used to direct the visitor to one of two possible locations, each with a likelihood of 50%.

It satisfies the basic requirement but I'm wondering if there might not be a better approach.

We have two sub directories, each one with a file within it, and one file at the root. Traffic generally hits the files in the sub dirs, but I wanted to create a root file to handle an event where a user might strip out everything in the URL but the domain.

Each of the files in the sub dirs use this logic to set the referrer:

```
function strleft($s1, $s2) {
    return substr($s1, 0, strpos($s1, $s2));
}
function selfURL() {
    if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
       $serverrequri = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    } else {
       $serverrequri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
    $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "";
    $protocol = strleft(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$s;
    $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
    $_SESSION['ref'] = $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$serverrequri;
}
selfURL();
```

The file at the root uses this logic to direct traffic:

```
$refurl = $_SESSION['ref'];
if (isset($refurl)) {
    header("Location: " . $refurl);
} else {
    $loc1 = "dir1/file.php";
    $loc2 = "dir2/file.php";
    $num = mt_rand(1, 100);
    if ($num > 50) {
        header("Location: " . $loc1);
    } else {
        header("Location: " . $loc2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to reimplement PHP sessions? What is the purpose? You might want to read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: is there any way "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']" wont be set?

Comment: This is pretty much decent code from my read. Don't expect you to get a lot of comments or answers as this is basically clean and proper from a language agnostic design perspective..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

null coalesce does exist in php according to the google (per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013493/coalesce-function-for-php )

```
$s = $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ?: "";
$protocol = strleft(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$s;
```

I'm not super familiar with php, but I think this should work from what I understand you're doing here.

Comment: nice! very useful, indeed.